# DDD. May I migrate my value object to an entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

So I'm trying to <del>refactor</del> rewrite my app in a DDD way. This is a simple app with 3 classes :

- Configuration(name)
- Environment(name)
- Property(key)

I use it to view and edit configuration files per environment. One `Configuration` can be viewed as a table with `Property` as row and `Environment` as column.

At this time, the `Configuration` is an entity and `Environment` and `Property` are value objects. But now I jave to implement the us ecase to set a `Value` to a `Property` for a given `Environment`. My first idea was this one :

```
class Configuration(name) {
   environments = SetOf[Environment]
   properties = SetOf[Property]

   setValue(property, environment, value) {
      knowEnv = environments.get(environment)
      knowEnv.setValue(property, value)
   }
}

class Environment(name) {
   properties = MapOf[Property, Value]

   setValue(property, value) {
     properties[property] = value
   }
}
```

But doing so will change my `Environment` from a value object to an entity. So I started to think (too much) and have trouble to find the "best" solution. That's why I came here to ask you, experts, how would you implement this use case.

Thanks

Comment: From what you've posted it does sound as though each `Environment` is a unique thing with an identity.  I'm guessing your environments are probably platforms or development environments?  So it probably should be an entity.

Comment: Ok thanks. You're right, they are platforms. So you say that they should be entities. But when I load the aggregate may I also load those entities or may I load them from a dedicated `EnvironmentRepository` ?

Comment: I've copied my previous comment and added a bit more into an 'answer' to hopefully answer your last comment.

Answer (score 4):

From what you've posted it does sound as though each `Environment` is a unique thing with an identity. I'm guessing your `Environments` are probably platforms or development environments? So it probably should be an entity.

It does sound as though your `Environment` could be edited, used, created, etc. independently of anything else.  In this case it probably shouldn't exist as part of another aggregate, so it should be it's own aggregate root (even if it's just a single entity).  Therefore it would have it's own repository.  This is a point that isn't blatantly obvious in the Evans DDD book, but an entity on it's own, is considered an aggregate root (made up of just one object).

If you wish to reference an `Environment` from another aggregate root, you would reference it by its unique id (not as a object reference).  You would then need another technique/method to retrieve these `Environments`.

This might seem to fly in the face of the old data-centric dogma, but you can do all sorts of things, like data caching your `Environments` (as there's probably a limited amount and they probably change infrequently) or employ CQRS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However while the `Environment` seems to be independent in my app it is not teh case. An `Environment` is attached to a `Configuration` and is not visible outside of the `Configuration`. That's the root of my design concern.

Comment: @Anonymous *"Not visible outside of"* is not a valid heuristic for aggregate design. You need to do more transactional analysis. Which entities will change together and separately, what data from which entities is needed to enforce business rules/invariants, how much concurrent access, etc.

Comment: @guillaume31 I agree, an 1:n relation between domain objects does not necessary mean that they belong to the same consistency boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Given the discussion and comments received on this questions I decided to keep the `Environment` immutable as value object. Setting a property value will then produce a new `Environment` :

```
class Configuration(name) {
   environments = SetOf[Environment]
   properties = SetOf[Property]

   setValue(property, environment, value) {
      knowEnv = environments.get(environment)
      updatedEnv = knowEnv.setValue(property, value)
      environments.replace(knowEnv, updatedEnv)
   }
}

class Environment(name) {
   properties = MapOf[Property, Value]

   setValue(property, value) {
     copy = new Environment(name)
     copy.properties = properties
     copy.properties[property] = value
     return copy
   }
}
```

It is simple to use and acceptable for our use cases.